# Jquery Autocomplete dynamic textbox issues

Tags: jquery, dynamic, autocomplete, textbox

```
$('.txtAlignLeft').live('focus.autocomplete', function(){
var $textBox = $(this);
var curId = $textBox.attr("id");
var vtxtmtlCode = $('#txtmtlCode').val();
pmidvalue = (curId).replace( /(^.+\D)(\d+)($)/i,'$2');

$(this).removeData('events').autocomplete(gMasterAjaxPath+"filename.php?vValid=3",{
    //delay:10,
    minChars:1,
    //cacheLength:20,
    //mustMatch:true,
    matchContains: true,
    mustMatch: false,
    //selectFirst: false,
    extraParams: {
    txtmtlCode: function() {return $('#txtmtlCode').val()},
},
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
        return value.split("#-#")[0]
    },
    formatResult: function(data, value) {
        return(value.split("#-#")[0]);
    }

}).result(function(event, item, data) {
    // Result updation

    });         
});
```

While I type a single character in my input box, the database hit occurs more than 10 to 20 times (In the console). And also when I click other tab or text-box the database hit contiously going ..
How can I solve this problem.. Is there any mistake in my code

Comment: why you go to database for each search,just get all data and keep in the result set and utilize it

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer commented out...

Use a combination of delay - it's in MS so 1000 = 1 second.

AND use minchar... so it will only search when say 2 or 3 chars has been entered.

Comment: Brain Thanks for your reply. I used delay:10 and minchars:1 but also am getting same problem. While I type the character, the database hit continuously going.. Please assist me that how can I solve this problem

Comment: personally I always encounter this... I usually also add some form of delay in the script end too... but the delay you have 10 = 0.01 use delay: 1000 or higher - 1000 - 1 second...seconds!